# T-SQL Check another table rows if match delete them

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, table

I am creating a script in SSIS where I want `table A` to check if rows exist in `table B`. If they exist, they must be deleted.

- `Table A` is an archive table named `Customer_archive`
- `Table B` is a table that will get updated frequently and is named `Customer_Information`.

The idea is that once a row is stored in `Customer_archive`, that row will not appear in `Customer_information`, even after `Customer_information` has been updated.

It has to check the entire row and not WHERE = 'something'.

Is it possible to do a `WHERE` clause that is a combination of 2 columns?

Comment: You can do this in SQL but wouldn't be easier for whatever procedure is archiving the rows from table B to A to delete these rows from B at the same time?

Comment: Yes that is also something that has to be done. however that will be done via a GUI. This is the process will be done when fetching new data. does it makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say anything about SSIS but in SQL you can check whether a whole row is identical to another (including checking for `NULL` values which can get rather complicated otherwise), using this technique, explained by @PaulWhite in his blog post: [Undocumented Query Plans: Equality Comparisons](http://web.archive.org/web/20180422151947/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/06/22/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.aspx) .

For example in you case. *"For any identical rows of table B and table A, delete those B rows"*:

```
DELETE b                        -- from table B: Customer_information
FROM Customer_archive AS a
  JOIN Customer_information AS b
  ON a.pk = b.pk
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT a.* INTERSECT SELECT b.*) ;
```

I have serious concerns though about efficiency when the tables are big - and an archive table by definition is going to be quite big. The `a.pk = b.pk` is not needed really, as the pk columns are obviously included in the row check of the `EXISTS` but I kept them for efficiency. Assuming that the two tables have the same primary key and that after a period, most of the archived rows have been already deleted from table B, the PK indexes will have very few matching values so the join will be relatively fast - and using the row checks only for matching pk values.

Comment: Well it can be cut down to 3 columns, Servername, Customer and IP, (a compound of that) However since Table B has been done with INTO (becuase it a result of 4 table joins), it does not have a PK, if that a.pk = b.pk stands for?

Comment: Does tableB have the same (3) columns as tableA?

Comment: They are identical structured so yes.

Comment: You can then simply use `ON EXISTS (SELECT a.* INTERSECT SELECT b.*) ;` and skip the PK check. I added it for efficiency, because I assumed that you'd have a primary key (and an index on it in both tables).

Comment: Usually i have PK on all my tables, however this part...hmmm is a bit tricky. Thanks! i will try it out. 
Is it correctly understood what with that query i can say:

Exists (SELECT a.Servername, a.Customer, a.IP INTERSECT SELECT
b.Servername, b.Customer, b.IP) to increase efficiency and the rows from table a will be deleted if exist in table b?

Comment: It's the other way around. `DELETE b...` means that rows from table B (customer) will be deleted, not from A (archive). But yes, you can use `Exists (SELECT a.Servername, a.Customer, a.IP INTERSECT SELECT b.Servername, b.Customer, b.IP)`